# Img in select tag not showing on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select

This is my code, it works perfectly on mozilla, but not on chrome.

my code:

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

option {
  background: url(image/flags/bg.png) no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you share your html ? moreover changing select option's background is nearly impossible with simple css.

Comment: Go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) and paste your html and css code and share the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not suppose to show. You can't set `background-image` to an option tag.

But you can use a jquery plugin called `select2`.

http://select2.github.io/select2/#templating

[image: Plugin's screen shot]